# Sending a foreign key value to a Create action

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm developing a simple project tracking website. A "Project" has "Tasks", and a "Task" has "Subtasks".
With the default scaffolding, when creating a "Task", I have to manually select the "ProjectId" field of the "Task".
I want to have it set up, that I will only be able to create a "Task" from within the "Project Detail" view.
I'm wondering how I can make it so I don't have to manually select the "ProjectId" when creating a new task.
Here are snippets:

This is part of the Create.cshtml for the Task as auto generated by Visual Studio:

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProjectId, "Project Id")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("ProjectId", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProjectId)
    </div>
```

This results in a drop down box where I have to manually select a project id.

This is the default "Create" action from the "Task" controller:

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.ProjectId = new SelectList(db.Projects, "Id", "Id");
        ViewBag.StatusId = new SelectList(db.Status, "Id", "Name");
        ViewBag.TaskTypeId = new SelectList(db.TaskTypes, "Id", "Name");
        return View();
    }
```

What I would like is something like this:

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.ProjectId = RouteData.Values["Id"];
        ViewBag.StatusId = new SelectList(db.Status, "Id", "Name");
        ViewBag.TaskTypeId = new SelectList(db.TaskTypes, "Id", "Name");
        return View();
    }
```

Somewhere I would have to set myTask.ProjectId = ViewBag.ProjectId. But I don't know where.
Is this even the right way of doing it? Or is there a better way?

Thanks

Comment: Are you wanting to actually set the default selected value of the `ProjectId` dropdown on load of the `Create` page? Is this correct?

Comment: sure. unless there's a better way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that you need the `DropDownList` and not just a hidden input with a fixed value?

It sounds like you want the value to be set and no visual representation of it should even be visible. If this is the case, you just pass your ID in the model and then bind it to a hidden input.

Comment: yes. thats exacltly what I'm looking for. it should be set in the back end, and the user should not have the option to select the project id.

Comment: Then your approach with passing it in `RouteData` sounds ok. Just instead of a DropDownList, use a hidden input in the view.

Comment: this is how far i got with that. In the Task create view:

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ProjectId, "Project Id")

Answer (score 1):

Setting the default value of the `ProjectId` isn't as difficult as you think, there is an overload for `SelectList` that takes an `object selectedValue`.

Replace this:

```
ViewBag.ProjectId = new SelectList(db.Projects, "Id", "Name");
```

With this (I've used 2 in this case as the selected Id):

```
ViewBag.ProjectId = new SelectList(db.Projects, "Id", "Name", 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities come to my mind.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var task = new Task()  { ProjectId = your_predefined_value };
    ViewBag.Projects = new SelectList(db.Projects, "Id", "Id");
    ViewData.Model = task;
    return View();
}
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ProjectId, (SelectList)ViewBag.Projects)
```

DropDownListFor will pre-select the Item from ViewBag.Projects whose Id matches x.ProjectId

Another way is to set the `Selected` Property of SelectListItem to true on the particular Item.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.Projects = new List<SelectListItem>() { 
        new SelectListItem() 
        {
            Value = "1",
            Text = "Project 1",
            Selected = true
        }
    };
    //...
}
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownList("ProjectId", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Projects)
```